# 3D equivalent of the curve function in R?

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

The `curve` function in R provides a simple way to plot a function. For example, this will plot a straight line

```
f1 <- function(x) x
curve(f1, from=-1, to=1)
```

**Is there an equivalent function in R which takes a function with two argument (e.g., `x` and `y`) and ranges for both variables and produces a 3D plot?**

For example, imagine I had the following function

```
f2 <- function(x, y) x + y
```

Is there a command similar to the following?

```
curve_3d(f2, x_range=c(-1, 1), y_range=c(-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `surface3d` function in package:rgl looks like a good match. It would be very simple to create a wrapper that would take your function, create an x-y set of vectors with `seq()` and then pass those vectors to `outer` with your f2 as the FUN argument, and then call `surface3d`.

There is also a `persp3d` which the authors (Duncan Murdoch and perhaps others) say is "higher level" and it does appear to add axes by default which surface3d does not.

```
curve_3d <- function(f2, x_range=c(-1, 1), y_range=c(-1, 1), col=1:6 ){ 
       if (!require(rgl) ) {stop("load rgl")}
       xvec <- seq(x_range[1], x_range[2], len=15)
        yvec <- seq(y_range[1], y_range[2], len=15)
       fz <- outer(xvec, yvec, FUN=f2)
       open3d()
       persp3d( xvec, yvec, fz, col=col) }
curve_3d(f2)
snapshot3d("out3dplane.png")
```

[image: Rotatable pseudo3d plot of plane]

Now that I think about it further, you could have done something similar with `persp()` or `wireframe()`. The "trick" is using outer(..., FUN=fun). And as I think about it even further ... the ability to use it with `outer` depends on it being composed of all vectorized operations. If they were not vectorized, we would need to rewrite with `Vectorize` or `mapply`.

Answer (score 2):

See `curve3d()` in `package:emdbook`, which is a wrapper for `wireframe()`, `persp3d()`, and more.

```
library(emdbook)
# bivariate normal density with emdbook::curve3d
curve3d(expr = dmvnorm(x=c(x,y), mu = c(0,0), Sigma = diag(2)), 
    from = c(-3,-3), to = c(3,3), n = 100, sys3d = "wireframe")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have an interactive plot with the `plot3Drgl` package.

```
library(plot3Drgl)

f <- function(x,y) x+y
x <- y <- seq(-4,4,len=20)
z <- outer(x, y, f)

persp3Drgl(z=z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `persp3d()` function can take a function as an argument.  See `?persp3d.function`.

It allows two kinds of surface to be plotted:  a function of `x` and `y` as you want, and a parametric surface, where `x`, `y` and `z` are all functions of two other variables.

For your example, it's as simple as

```
f2 <- function(x, y) x + y
persp3d(f2)
```

but of course you can add all sorts of frills, like having the colour depend on `z`, changing the range of `x` and `y`, etc.