# How to plot a regression plane with an interaction in rgl

Tags: r, plot, regression, interaction, rgl

I want to plot the regression surface from a model with an interaction term using `rgl`'s interactive plotting system.  It is easy to plot a regression plane for a model without an interaction term using:

```
plot3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y1, type="s", col="yellow", size=1)
planes3d(a=coef(mod1)[2], b=coef(mod1)[3], c=-1, d=coef(mod1)[1], alpha=.5)
```

However, when the plane twists, this seems to be more difficult.  Following on this question: [3D equivalent of the curve function in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875941/3d-equivalent-of-the-curve-function-in-r), I am trying:

```
f2 <- function(x, y) as.vector(coef(mod2)%*%c(1, x, y, x*y))

curve_3d <- function(f2, x_range=c(0, 40), y_range=c(0, 40)){ 
  if (!require(rgl) ) {stop("load rgl")}

  xvec <- seq(x_range[1], x_range[2], by=1)
  yvec <- seq(y_range[1], y_range[2], by=1)
  fz   <- outer(xvec, yvec, FUN=f2)
  persp3d(xvec, yvec, fz, alpha=.5)
}
open3d()
plot3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y2, type="s", col="yellow", size=1)
curve_3d(f2)
```

But, it's not working.  (I've tried some other things as well, but I'm keeping this short.)  My main problem so far seems to be with `f2`; however, I will also want this to look like `planes3d`, and I'm not sure if this is going to give me a wireframe.

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(897)
x1 = rep(c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40), times=25)
x2 = rep(c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40), each=25)
y2 = 37 + 0.7*x1 + 1.2*x2 - 0.05*x1*x2 + rnorm(125, mean=0, sd=5)
mod2 = lm(y2~x1*x2)
open3d()
plot3d(x=x1, y=x2, z=y2, type="s", col="yellow", size=1)
curve_3d(f2)
```

Comment: The usual way is to use `predict` with a model, rather than trying to calculate the prediction from a coefficient vector. You are not saying what errors you are getting, but it looks as though your arguments are not the same as the ones you are passing. `curve3d` is supposed to get three arguments and you are only passing one.

Comment: I'd be happy with that. How do you get the predictions from the model? I tried using `z=mod2$fitted.values`, but it also didn't work. (I've tried several things.)

Comment: The specific error that I've been able to track down is "Error in coef(mod2) %*% c(1, x, y, x * y) : non-conformable arguments".

Comment: For worked illustrations, I expect a data object.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Better solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147595/plot-3d-plane-true-regression-surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grd <- expand.grid(x1=unique(x1), x2=unique(x2) )
grd$pred <-predict(mod2, newdata=grd)
persp3d(x=unique(grd[[1]]), y=unique(grd[[2]]), 
              z=matrix(grd[[3]],5,5), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Why  z=matrix(grd[[3]], 5, 5) rather than z=matrix(grd[[3]])? That's the only bit I'm not following.