# Generate a regression plane with predict function

Tags: r, regression, predict, plane, r-grid

I want to plot a regression plane for my data:

structure(list(L = c(96.4155, 76.803, 71.5615, 68.193, 65.6975, 
74.627, 67.82, 64.26, 62.06, 60.35, 68.284, 63.7, 61.04, 59.05, 
57.56, 64.2695, 60.69, 58.47, 56.78, 55.42, 61.3715, 58.27, 56.42, 
54.91, 53.65), a = c(-0.8375, -20.47, -22.1875, -22.6125, -22.5845, 
-2.2415, -12.91, -16.16, -17.9, -18.77, -2.4, -10.28, -13.64, 
-15.33, -16.37, -2.4495, -8.66, -11.74, -13.46, -14.55, -2.4645, 
-7.58, -10.38, -12.06, -13.09), b = c(1.437, -24.5915, -29.3275, 
-31.892, -33.524, -5.151, -15.22, -19.61, -22.65, -24.8, -6.239, 
-13.24, -17.11, -19.64, -21.55, -6.7845, -12.18, -15.45, -17.68, 
-19.47, -7.124, -11.53, -14.38, -16.41, -17.89)), .Names = c("L", 
"a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")

I tried an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928716/how-to-plot-a-regression-plane-with-an-interaction-in-rgl). And that is my try:

```
L<-X[1:25,2]
a<-X[1:25,3]
b<-X[1:25,4]
mod2 = lm(L~a*b)
open3d()
plot3d(x=a, y=b, z=L, type="s", col="red", size=1)

grd <- expand.grid(x1=a, x2=b )
grd$pred <-predict(mod2, newdata=grd)
persp3d(x=unique(grd[,1]), y=unique(grd[,2]), 
    z=matrix(grd[,3]), add=TRUE, alpha=0.5)
```

The 3d-Plot looks fine, but for the grid I get this error:

```
Error in persp3d.default(x = grd[, 1], y = grd[, 2], z = matrix(grd[,  : 
increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
```

Where is the problem in my code and is there maybe another way to solve my problem? Thx for your help!

Update:

I've tried it with plane3d() but got this error:

```
Error in segments(x, z1, x + y.max * yx.f, z2 + yz.f * y.max, lty = ltya,  : 
cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates
```

However, after searching for other solution I figured out that my intention was wrong. I'm searching for something like this ...

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmQG1.jpg)
[intention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GafMJ.png)

...but have no clue how to attain it or if it is even possible with my actual knowledge of R. Someone any idea?

Update2:

I've tried the scatter3d() function with this code:

```
scatter3d(a,b,L,fit="smooth")
```

but got this error:

```
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom
```

I already found, that I have to use choose.k to adjust the degrees of freedom, but it is always explained for the gam functions and I have no clue how to use it in the scatter3d function. Any idea?

Comment: check out the `scatterplot3d()` function in the `car` package?

Comment: I think you mean the scatter3d() function?

Comment: Do you have a hint for my problem explained in the updates above?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've solved my problem with a very nasty solution:

```
data <- structure(list(L = c(96.4155, 76.803, 71.5615, 68.193, 65.6975, 74.627, 67.82, 64.26,    
62.06, 60.35, 68.284, 63.7, 61.04, 59.05, 57.56, 64.2695, 60.69, 58.47, 56.78, 55.42, 
61.3715, 58.27, 56.42, 54.91, 53.65), a = c(-0.8375, -20.47, -22.1875, -22.6125, 
-22.5845, -2.2415, -12.91, -16.16, -17.9, -18.77, -2.4, -10.28, -13.64, -15.33, -16.37, 
-2.4495, -8.66, -11.74, -13.46, -14.55, -2.4645, -7.58, -10.38, -12.06, -13.09), b = 
c(1.437, -24.5915, -29.3275, -31.892, -33.524, -5.151, -15.22, -19.61, -22.65, -24.8, 
-6.239, -13.24, -17.11, -19.64, -21.55, -6.7845, -12.18, -15.45, -17.68, -19.47, -7.124, 
-11.53, -14.38, -16.41, -17.89)), .Names = c("L", "a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 25L),
class = "data.frame")

L<-data[1:25,1]
a<-data[1:25,2]
b<-data[1:25,3]
plot3d(a,b,L, col="red", size="3", xlab="a*", ylab="b*", zlab="L*", main=NULL)

#Generate order for quadruplets

a[c(1:64)] <- a[c(1,2,7,6,2,3,8,7,3,4,9,8,4,5,10,9,
                  6,7,12,11,7,8,13,12,8,9,14,13,9,10,15,14,
                  11,12,17,16,12,13,18,17,13,14,19,18,14,15,20,19,
                  16,17,22,21,17,18,23,22,18,19,24,23,19,20,25,24)] 
b[c(1:64)] <- b[c(1,2,7,6,2,3,8,7,3,4,9,8,4,5,10,9,
                  6,7,12,11,7,8,13,12,8,9,14,13,9,10,15,14,
                  11,12,17,16,12,13,18,17,13,14,19,18,14,15,20,19,
                  16,17,22,21,17,18,23,22,18,19,24,23,19,20,25,24)] 
L[c(1:64)] <- L[c(1,2,7,6,2,3,8,7,3,4,9,8,4,5,10,9,
                  6,7,12,11,7,8,13,12,8,9,14,13,9,10,15,14,
                  11,12,17,16,12,13,18,17,13,14,19,18,14,15,20,19,
                  16,17,22,21,17,18,23,22,18,19,24,23,19,20,25,24)] 

quads3d(a[1:64],b[1:64],L[1:64],col="red",alpha=0.5)
```

Is there any function who does exactly the same?