# Drawing a regression surface with an interaction in a 3D figure in R

Tags: r, rgl, r-car

Using `car::scatter3d()`, I am trying to create a 3D figure with a regression surface indicating an interaction between a categorical and a continuous variable. Partly following the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14932045/3237850), I obtained a figure below.

[image]

The figure is obviously wrong in that the regression surface does not reach one of the values of the categorical variable. The problem perhaps lies in the use of the `rgl::persp3d()` (the last block of the code below), but I have not been able to identify what exactly I'm doing wrongly. Could someone let me know what I'm missing and how to fix the problem?

```
library(rgl)
library(car)
n <- 100
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(n, 0, 10)
set.seed(1)
z <- sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
set.seed(1)
y <- 0.5 * x + 0.1 * z + 0.3 * x * z + rnorm(n, sd = 1.5)
d <- data.frame(x, z, y)
scatter3d(y ~ x + z, data = d, 
  xlab = "continuous", zlab = "categorical", ylab = "outcome",
  residuals = FALSE, surface = FALSE
)

d2 <- d
d2$x <- d$x / (max(d$x) - min(d$x))
d2$y <- d$y / (max(d$y) - min(d$y))
mod <- lm(y ~ x * z, data = d2)
grd <- expand.grid(x = unique(d2$x), z = unique(d2$z))
grd$pred <- predict(mod, newdata = grd)
grd <- grd[order(grd$z, grd$x), ]

# The problem is likely to lie somewhere below.
persp3d(x = unique(grd$x), y = unique(grd$z), 
  z = matrix(grd$pred, length(unique(grd$z)), length(unique(grd$x))), 
  alpha = 0.5,
  col = "blue",
  add = TRUE,
  xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = ""
)
```

I prefer sticking to `car::scatter3d()` in drawing the original graph because I already made several figures with `car::scatter3d()` and want to make this figure consistent with them as well.

Comment: If `z` is a factor then by definition it can only take on values `0` and `1`; values between 0 ad 1 are meaningless. So there is no 3D surface, there are two curves: y vs x when z=0 and y vs x when z=1.

Comment: I want to demonstrate that a factor as an independent variable is just a special case of regression modeling with continuous variables, and for this purpose, I thought it could help to have a figure like the above (because I'd put a similar figure with continuous variables). But you are right that most part of the surface is meaningless and having a surface drawn can be misleading...

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861588/5784831) solves your problem? I guess only the formula for `z` will change...