# Plot function in R with two input variables

Tags: r, function, plot

I have the following function in R:

```
n<- function(theta){
d=theta[1]
z=theta[2]
Nh= c(1819, 1018)
N= sum(Nh)
sigmah= c(0.013, 0.0155)
n=sum(Nh*sigmah)^2/(N^2*d^2/z^2+sum(Nh*sigmah^2))
return(n)
}
```

I would like to plot the function n over a range of inputs for d and z. How could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: try `curve3d` from the `emdbook` package?

Comment: @BondedDust: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875941/3d-equivalent-of-the-curve-function-in-r feels like a better match to this question

Comment: There are of course many ways to represent data in a third dimension. `lattice::contourplot` (illustrated in the example offered as a duplicate),  lattice::levelplot`, and the methods available in package:rgl in addition to the curve3d method mentioned by Ben.

Comment: @BenBolker: If you will then vote to close on that basis I can retract my close vote, but it's not possible to modify a close vote.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what range of values is appropriate, but this produces something not too crazy:

```
library("emdbook")
curve3d(n(c(x,y)),xlim=c(1,2),ylim=c(1,2))
```